# Iterate over array treating index 0 differently

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I found many questions and answers dealing with iterating over arrays but did not find one explaining how to iterate over the contents of an array, identifying and treating index 0 differently.

The reason for this is that I have an incoming stream of data and I want to display them as a plot of their value over time. An easy way to do this is to make a `CGMutablePathRef`, compute x and y coordinates and then `CGPathAddLineToPoint` to continue drawing the line. Of course the path has to start somewhere and so for the first index I need to set the y coordinate to 0 offset, calculate the x coordinate and set the beginning of the path with `CGPathMoveToPoint`.

What I did was handle index 0, then copy the array and discard index 0, and processed the remaining items in the copied array (all but 0). I could also have just set a boolean false, and if false in the loop processed the point as index 0 then set the boolean true. Both these approaches are a bit messy.

The part I really don't like is copying the array of values every time the path is generated. Is there an easy way to iterate over an array beginning at index 1?

Is there some convenient array syntax I'm missing?

```
    var yOffset = 0.0
    temperaturePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(temperaturePath, nil, xOffsetForTemperature(temperatures[0]), yOffset)
    var remainingTemperatures = temperatures
    remainingTemperatures.removeAtIndex(0)

    for value in remainingTemperatures {

        yOffset += verticalAdvanceAmount
        let temperatureXOffset = xOffsetForTemperature(value)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(temperaturePath, nil, temperatureXOffset, yOffset)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to split the array *permanently* into the first element and everything else, use `removeAtIndex`, because it returns the thing that was removed:

```
var temperatures = // ...
let first = temperatures.removeAtIndex(0) // alters temperatures
```

If the goal is to derive the first element and everything else *without* altering the original array, you can take a slice:

```
let first = temperatures.first!
let rest = temperatures[1..<temperatures.count]
```

But this is a special case where there's a shortcut; use `dropFirst`, which leaves the original array untouched:

```
let first = temperatures.first!
let rest = dropFirst(temperatures)
```

(Note that I am deriving temporary variables `first` and `rest` for clarity only. In real life, you can skip them. Both `temperatures[1..<temperatures.count]` and `dropFirst(temperatures)` are directly enumerable with `for...in`.)

Comment: I'm not sure if that solves the problem - temperatures accumulates new values so I can't destroy it on each draw. I would still need to make a copy of the array before processing that way wouldn't I?

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. I did not suggest that you "destroy" anything! You asked for cleaner syntax and I provided some.

Comment: I mean I can't discard any values from the temperatures array because they should be drawn every drawRect: - I was hoping there was some range modifier to "for value in temperatures" that would process everything but index 0

Comment: And see this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_basic_array_properties_and_methods

Comment: I'm an idiot. You should use `dropFirst`. I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a slice.

```
temperaturePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(temperaturePath, nil, xOffsetForTemperature(temperatures[0]), yOffset)

yOffset = 0.0
for value in temperatures.dropFirst() {
    yOffset += verticalAdvanceAmount
    let temperatureXOffset = xOffsetForTemperature(value)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(temperaturePath, nil, temperatureXOffset, yOffset)
}
```

More details in [*Swift Standard Library Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html) and [this article by Nate Cook](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/09/slicing-for-speed/).

You could choose to store your data as an array of `CGPoint`, in which case you could just use [`CGContextAddLines`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextAddLines) to do the initial move and add all the line segments in one call.

You might find once you have a lot of data points that it's inefficient to stroke the whole path over and over, in which case you might find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12162860/77567) helpful.

Comment: `for value in dropFirst(temperatures)`

Comment: That linked answer is along the lines of what I was going to do but I realised I only need very simple for now. I just discard some number of points from the beginning of the array every time the array is too large to plot across the screen - so scrolling fine but no history. I wish I could mark more than one answer correct here.